# Understanding the .toggle function and hiding/unhiding buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, show-hide

I have a text input area that chops the string up into an array and makes buttons out of it for each word. I want to be able to hide each word seperate from eachother on('click') on the button. I tried to use the Jquery.toggle function but this only hides all of my buttons. I cant make them re-appear. Is there a way to fade them out and make them hidden and be able to unhide them.

I already tried searching the internet. Couldn't really come to a solution actually considered writing my own toggle but that just seems off. Is the only way you can use toggle to actually have a static button thats clickable that hides or unhides a piece of code.

Its obviously kinda weird to be able to unhide something thats hidden when there is no button that shows/hides all.

```
    let createText=$('<textarea/>', {
        'id':'Text',
        'placeholder':'Text',
        'class':'form-control col col-md-5',
        'rows':'10'
    }).on("input", function() {
        let woorden = $(this).val().split(/(\s)/g);
        $('#outputButtons').empty();
        for (let i = 0; i < woorden.length; i++) {
            if (woorden[i].replace(/\s/g, "") != "") {
                let outputBtn=$('<button/>', {
                    'class': 'btn btn-secondary mt-2 mr-2'
                }).html(woorden[i])
                $('#outputButtons').append(outputBtn);                        
            }
        }
    });

    let outputButtons = $('<div/>', {
        'class':'col',
        'id':'outputButtons'
    }).on('click', function() {
        $('#outputButtons').toggle(1000); 

    });
```

How would I go on, on actually hiding/unhiding the buttons seperate from eachother. Is this possible without a static button that shows/hides all ?

Thanks in advance for reading, I am a new programmer and there is just so much information and things you have to keep in mind at the same time which makes it confusing from time to time. SO sorry if this post is confusing.

Comment: Could you please include a working example snippet in your question (with HTML-code)? Please also consult the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as how to include such an example, it tends to get bloated with unnecessary hard-to-read code if done wrong.

Comment: I almost have no HTML code in my script, I append everything with  Javascript to my HTML

I include a screenshot:
https://gyazo.com/b2700df133f55bb264a509e273258a06

As you can see every seperate word is a button, when I click them now with my current code I hide all of them and I can't make them re-appear. I wish to hide them seperate from eachother and actually be able to make them re-appear seperate of eachother.

Comment: It doesn't really matter how little amount of HTML-code you have, it's about providing a working example so people can reproduce the problem on their own. Debugging code by just looking at it is usually very tedious and time consuming. Please read [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use toggle for buttons!

Add this class to buttons you want to disable

```
.disable{
   cursor: not-allowed;
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

For changing the status you can use jquery

```
$("#id").toggleClass('disable');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your code:

Write the below css class:

```css
.hide{
opacity: 0;
}
```

Then apply on output buttons("on click" function):

```js
$(this).toggleClass("hide")
```